# Injecting Stateful bean Inside Request Scope Session Bean

Tags: jsf, ejb

What is the difference between injecting a stateful ejb bean inside request scoped session bean vs injecting a stateless ejbbean inside request scoped session bean? Does request scoped bean creates a new instance for stateful bean each time it is called?

Comment: I understand what you said. I'm more concerned about how to store session in an EJB applicaton using stateful bean .Can u elaborate on it? How to call stateful session bean to perform business logic from jsf maanged bean?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Actually, I can store session using JSF/CDI session scoped beans and use stateless beans for most of the business logic but then it really makes me think what is the use of stateful  bean then. I thought that stateful beans are used for storing session and it is the replacement of HTTP session object.

Answer (score 2):

- Before a **stateful** session bean is deployed, it is in the **Does Not Exist** state. Upon successful deployment, the EJB container does any required dependency injection on the bean and it goes into
  the **Ready** state. At this point, the bean is ready to have its methods
  called by a client application.
- When a **stateful** session bean is in the Ready state, the EJB
  container may decide to **passivate** it, that is, to move it from the
  main memory to the secondary storage. When this happens, the bean
  goes into the **Passive** state.
- If an instance of a **stateful** session bean hasn't been accessed for a
  period of time, the EJB container will set the bean to the **Does Not
  Exist** state.
- A **stateless** session bean life cycle contains only the **Does Not Exist**
  and **Ready** states, stateless session beans **are never passivated**.
- **RequestScoped** Bean lives as long as the HTTP request-response lives.

so your stateless bean inside a request scoped backing bean will destroyed after HTTP request-response but the stateful one will go to the passive state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can u elaborate on how to store session using stateful bean by calling/injecting it from jsf managed bean?

Comment: I can store state in JSF session scoped beans and use stateless bean for business logic but i want to try to use stateful bean for storing session as stateful bean is the replacement of HTTP session object.

Comment: You're welcome, I don't know exactly what do you want to do and why you are using a stateful bean inside a request scoped backing bean but you can use **FacesContext.getExternalContext().getSession/getSessionMap() ** to retrive or store session's object. good luck.